# Generating function for this series

Tags: generating-functions

The question is:
find the generating function for $(f_0,f_1,f_2,...)$
where $f_{n} = f_{n-1}+ 2f_{n-3}$
and $f_0 =0$ and 
$f_1 = f_2 = 1
$
I have solved this and reached G(x) = $(x-2)\over(2{x^3} + x - 1)$
but I see in Wolfram Alpha that this is not the answer

Can anyone Help?

---

update:
my solution :
$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^n = \sum_{n=3}^\infty f_nx^n + f_0+ f_1 + f_2 = \sum_{n=3}^\infty f_nx^n + 2$$

$$G(x)-2 =\sum_{n=3}^\infty (f_{n-1}+ 2f_{n-3})x^n = \sum_{n=3}^\infty f_{n-1}x^n + 2\sum_{n=3}^\infty f_{n-3}x^n$$
$$G(x) -2 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty f_nx^{n+1} + 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^{n+3} $$
$$G(x) - 2 = x(G(x)-1) + 2x^3G(x) $$
$$ G(x) = {(x-2)\over(2x^3+x-1)}$$

so whats wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Comment: Also, fix your typesetting (use MathJax).

Comment: I suppose that your answer is effectively wrong. The development of the $G(x)$ you wrote is $2+x+x^2+5 x^3+7 x^4+9 x^5+19 x^6+O\left(x^7\right)$ which seems to be in contradiction with $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Please check I didn't change anything while editing, there was a lot to do.

Comment: Minor problem, it should be $x(G(x)-x-1)$ in next to last line. But there is another problem elsewhere.

Comment: Same issue at the beginning, first line of update, you need to add $x+x^2$, not $2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why? Could you Explain Why it should be $x(G(x)-x-1)$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes i think this is the answer! Bad Mistake!!

Comment: I would rather explain first line of update. But here goes about first comment. The sum of the terms from $2$ to infinity is $G(x)$ minus sum of first two terms. But I got the first term wrong.  Same at the very beginning, the first three terms don't add up to $2$, but to $0+x+x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue is that you go from
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_nx^n
$$
to
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty f_nx^n + f_0 + f_1 + f_2 = \sum_{n=3}^\infty f_nx^n + 2
$$
which is not right. It ought to be
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty f_nx^n + f_0 + f_1x + f_2x^2 = \sum_{n=3}^\infty f_nx^n + x + x^2
$$
instead.

Comment: And the line next to last line should be $x(G(x)-x)$
the final answer is $G(x) = {x\over {1-x-2x^3}}$